# Please help me out with sine and cosine

Tags: math, graphics, trigonometry

I know that sin is `opposite/hypotenuse` in a right angled triangle and cos is `adjacent/hypotenuse`. But when i come across functions like for Eg. In Flash :-

`something.x = Math.cos(someNumber) * someotherNumber;`

`something.z = Math.sin(someNumber) * someotherNumber;`

what does it actually do? My stack overflows when i see such things. I don't understand trignometry that well. What is the opposite and what exactly is the hypotenuse in the above lines? And why does it use `cos` on one line and `sin` on other? Is there any shortcut for calculating these kind of things? Please help me. These things i didn't understand even when i took computer graphics classes and unfortunately even when i asked to my lecturer, she always used to tell, these things you already studied when you were in 7th grade. But i really don't remember that i studied anything like this.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You won't get much shorter than `Math.sin` and `Math.cos` in Flash. In any case, this isn't really a programming question. If you don't understand trigonometry, then find a book on the subject and read it, or browse the hundreds of trigonometry tutorials you can find online.

Comment: cosx=a/h->h*cox = a, so the something.x value is probably the adjacent side...Calculations like these can be used to determine lengths as i have shown (at the most basic level). Try researching more on google or even wikipedia

Comment: this is really linear algebra/trigonometry, and only borderline programming related. I'm not going to vote to close, but you should consider looking for some maths text instead. Basically, `something.x` is the opposite and `someotherNumber` is the hypotenuse. The two lines calculate the two edges of a right triangle given the length of the hypotenuse and an angle (`someNumber`, probably in radians).

Comment: What does `Math.cos(someNumber)` and `Math.sin(someNumber)` do clearly *is* a programming question.  The computer thinks of sin and cos quite differently than we do.

Comment: @Rising Star: the OP's question clearly *isn't* at that level of subtlety.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos: I am trying to make a carousel in Flash and so this clearly is a programming question i believe. But your advise holds true about reading tutorials.

Comment: @Nitesh: The fact that the question arose while you were trying to solve a programming problem is immaterial. You are basically asking for an explanation of some math concepts. The context could just as easily have come from a battlefield gunner wondering how high to tilt his cannon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend you read the [Wikipedia entry on the unit circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle).

In short, if you are looking for the coordinates of a point located on a circle of radius 1 at a given counter-clockwise angle from the right-most point of the circle, its y coordinate will be given by the sine of this angle, and its x coordinate will be given by the cosine of this angle.

If your circle has a radius of something other than 1, you must multiply by that radius, hence the `*someotherNumber` in your equations.

Answer (score 2):

http://cda.morris.umn.edu/~mcquarrb/Precalculus/Animations/SineCosineAnim.html

The sine and cosine functions are often used to calculate a coordinate for a point of which you know the distance and the angle.

Answer (score 1):

You've asked two questions:

1) What is the opposite and what exactly is the hypotenuse in the above lines?

First of all, `someNumber` is going to represent an angle measured in radians.  The `cos` and `sin` values represent the sine and cosine of that angle.  Usually, we think of a triangle with hypotenuse 1, so that cosine and sine become like (x,y) co-ordinates in a plane.

2) What does it actually do?

Although you may think of sine and cosine as something you would need to know the length of three sides of a triangle to calculate, there are methods to calculate them using ordinary arithmetic (addition, subtraction, multiplication, division).  When the code is executed, some such method is likely used to perform the calculation.  Here is one of the most famous examples: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series

Answer (score 1):

The sine and cosine functions have been generalised for all real values. See:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Unit-circle_definitions

This is what is computed by the those calls.